# How to setup a SQL Cluster between 2 sites in active passive mode without shared storage

Tags: sql-server, clustering, disaster-recovery, license

we need to install SQL at 2 sites, 1 primary and 1 DR. We don't to pay for license for the DR and need to know how will we setup a SQL cluster/replication/alwayson/bag or any other method that will keep the Sql service down at DR and only when primary is unavailble then the SQL service starts.

currently we installed a BAG and the 2 sites have sql service running, though we use only one site at a time, Auditors flagged it as active/active while we thought it was active/passive.

thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Hi Erik, they said that if the sql service is running that mean it is active.

Comment: I'd contest the bejeezus out of that. The only time I've seen it get called active is if you're offloading something there, like queries, backups, or checkdb. But you can't really do that with a BAG.

Comment: Yes, we did and they did remove for previous setup but now we need to redo the setup to be fully passive. that's where am stuck, how to make it fully passive.

Comment: the auditors are flat-out wrong, especially with the limitations of a BAG. contest it, and then push for new auditors.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type of replication. If you can access only 1 Primary DB at a time then its active/passive. If you can access both then its active/active.

Overview : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/sql-server-business-continuity-dr?view=sql-server-2017

Details : Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Licensing guide

Comment: thanks shahrulanwar, but how do i setup a completely passive setup? any links, pictures, guides you can forward me to.